# How to access user music library on iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, ios13, apple-music, apple-musickit

Since iOS 9.3 we can use the API `SKCloudServiceController.requestAuthorization` to ask permission to access the user's music library. [The documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skcloudservicecontroller/1620609-requestauthorization) says that the only change to this API on Xcode 11 was the support for tvOS, which should not change anything on iOS (which is the platform I'm using).

But, since Xcode 11 beta 4 I've noticed that the `SKCloudServiceController.requestAuthorization` callback does not get called.

My question is: is there a new API to ask for music library access or is this a iOS 13 bug?

I've found two unresolved discussions on Apple Developer Forums with related issues:

[SKCloudServiceController.requestAuthorization not working on iOS 13](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/372170)

[MPMedialLibrary.requestAuthorization not working on iOS13 devices](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/119399)

Comment: Same here, also since beta 4. Maybe something to do with iTunes splitting into separate services (Music, Podcasts, etc). That's just my opinion, I don't have any inside info. No updated class methods I'm aware of. If I come across a new class or something, I'll return and update my comment.

Comment: It was fixed on iOS 13 beta 5!

Comment: Ha. I was just coming here to update the thread. Yep, works great now.